# Get list of types for which templated member method is specialized

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, fsm

I wrote a following base code for my FSM implementation:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct BaseState {
    template <typename T>
    static bool canTransition() {
        if constexpr((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...)) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct StateMachine {
    std::variant<Ts...> active;

    template <typename T>
    bool activate() {
        const bool canTransition = std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.template canTransition<T>(); }, active);
        if (!canTransition) return false;

        std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.template onExit<T>(); }, active);
        active.template emplace<T>();
        
        return true;
    }
};

struct B;

struct A : BaseState<B> {
    template <typename T>
    void onExit() {}

    template <>
    void onExit<B>() { std::cout << "A -> B" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : BaseState<> {
    template <typename T>
    void onExit() {};
};

int main() {
    StateMachine<A, B> sm;

    sm.activate<B>(); // A -> B
    sm.activate<A>(); // Shouldn't switch state
}
```

`onExit` member method allows me to perform some actions based on new state type.

I want to automatically deduce A and B template parameters based on `onExit` specializations, so I do not need to manually specify all states that the certain state can transition to.

I was also thinking of moving `template <typename T> void onExit() {}` definition to `BaseState` class, however, It seems that you can't specialize inherited templated member methods.

As an alternative, I was thinking of returning boolean value from `onExit` method, indicating whether the state should be transitioned, like so:

```cpp
struct BaseState {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct StateMachine {
    std::variant<Ts...> active;

    template <typename T>
    bool activate() {
        const bool canTransition = std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.template onExit<T>(); }, active);
        if (!canTransition) return false;

        active.template emplace<T>();
        
        return true;
    }
};

struct B;

struct A : BaseState {
    template <typename T>
    bool onExit() { return false; }

    template <>
    bool onExit<B>() { std::cout << "A -> B" << std::endl; return true; }
};

struct B : BaseState {
    template <typename T>
    bool onExit() { return false; }
};

int main() {
    StateMachine<A, B> sm;

    sm.activate<B>(); // A -> B
    sm.activate<A>(); // Shouldn't switch state
}
```

however, I don't really like the idea of specifying retval manually.

What are my options?

Comment: "I want to automatically deduce A and B template parameters" - I don't get what you want to deduce exactly. Is it the `B` in `struct A : BaseState<B>` and the empty list in `struct B : BaseState<>`?

Comment: @Nelfeal sorry for not being clear enough. Yes, that’s exactly what I need. Having onExit specializations for A, B, C types, should deduce BaseState<A, B, C>

Comment: Alternatively, I could remove BaseState template and somehow get the type list of specializations in canTransition member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than deduce the pack `Ts...` for your current `BaseState`, you can use CRTP to check the existence of `Current::onExit<Next>` within it.

```
template <typename S>
struct BaseState {
    template <typename T>
    bool transition () {
        if constexpr (requires(S self) { self.template onExit<T>(); })
        {
            static_cast<S *>(this)->template onExit<T>();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct StateMachine {
    std::variant<Ts...> active;

    template <typename T>
    bool activate() {
        const bool transitioned = std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.template transition<T>(); }, active);
        if (transitioned) {
            active.template emplace<T>();    
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

struct B;

struct A : BaseState<A> {
    template <typename T>
    requires std::same_as<T, B>
    void onExit() { std::cout << "A -> B" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : BaseState<B> {
};
```

Comment: That's brilliant and exactly what I need. Not sure why I didn't come up with it.

Thank you very much.